# How can I avoid cross-threading issues in my WPF MVVM unit tests?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing

I've got a WPF project using MVVM pattern.

In a particular viewmodel I fill up an ObservableCollection periodically using a background task (Task class).

I use the code below to actually populate the collection:

```
    private void InitialiseAssignablePermissions()
    {
        var assignablePermissions = DetermineAssignablePermissions();

        CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => 
        {
            foreach (var ap in assignablePermissions)
            {
                AssignablePermissions.Add(ap);
            }
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly and my unit tests run happily and all go green.

However, if I have an ICollectionView connected to the ObservableCollection, when I run the tests I get a cross-threading exception and the tests fail. The exception happens when I first try to add an item to the collection. The code still runs happily though when the project is executed. I need the collection view because I want to filter the items.

The exception is:

```
This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its
SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.
```

The CurrentDispatcher class is a simple one I added for unit testing:

```
internal static class CurrentDispatcher
{
    internal static void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        if (App.Current != null)
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }
}
```

How can I add the collection view and still unit test?

Comment: Did you check that during unit test App.Current is not equal to null?  and you should also check if Dispatcher.Thread.IsAlive just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when writing tests for my WPF project. The problem is that your dispatcher is not running when you call invoke as you are running a test project.

You can get around this by running the dispatcher on a separate thread. As you'll probably notice, the incorrect stack trace is displayed on failures, so rather than rethrow the unhandled exception received from the dispatcher, I call assert.fail and append the stacktrace to the error message. If anyone knows of a better way to handle this, please let me know.

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
public static void RunTestInDispatcher(Action action)
    {
        failException = null;
        GetDispatcher().Invoke(action);

        if (failException != null)
        {
            Assert.Fail(string.Format("{0}\n{1}", failException.Message, failException.StackTrace));
        }
    }

    private static object dispatcherLock = new object();
    private static Dispatcher dispatcher = null;
    public static Dispatcher GetDispatcher()
    {
        lock (dispatcherLock)
        {
            if (dispatcher == null)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    lock (dispatcherLock)
                    {
                        dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                        dispatcher.UnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(dispatcher_UnhandledException);
                        Monitor.Pulse(dispatcherLock);
                    }
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }));

                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                t.Start();

                Monitor.Wait(dispatcherLock);
            }
        }
        return dispatcher;

    }

    static Exception failException = null;

    static void dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        failException = e.Exception;
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the test then gets wrapped in an action delegate? e.g. RunTestInDispatcher(() => { /* Actions and Asserts */ }); - This is what I tried but I still get the error.

Comment: You should wrap only the calls related to Dispatcher. Asserts should be outside.